# Can you use Microsoft Planner in a home environment?

Tags: office365, microsoft-planner

I have been using Planner in a business environment for a while, and would like to use it at home (for personal use) too.
I have a valid Office365 license, and all other apps I care about (Excel, Word, PowerPoint, Outlook, OneDrive) work fine; there is no issue with my licence. But it seems Planner is simply not available on the Office365 website.

Is Planner usage not possible without an Enterprise in-house server? Or how would I get into it?

Edit: neither Amazon nor the Microsoft shop offer to buy Planner in any form. The Microsoft Planner site (https://products.office.com/en-us/business/task-management-software) explains what it is and why it is great, but when you try to buy it, they forward you to the shop, where it is not available anywhere.
It looks like it is not a product that is separately sold.

Comment: As long as you have a valid license to the software you can install it on any machine you want.  However, Microsoft Planner, isn’t one of the applications you get with an Office 365 subscription (Viso and Project are also separate).

Comment: I suggest you contact your Microsoft Reseller and see if they can obtain a single license for you to purchase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia Microsoft Planner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Planner)
says this:

> Microsoft Planner is a planning application available on the Microsoft Office 365 platform. The application is available to **premium, business, and educational** subscribers to Office 365.

The same message is found in every other Microsoft announcement about Planner:

> All users with **eligible subscription plans** will automatically see the Planner tile appear in the Office 365 app launcher when it is available for them to use. No specific action by Office 365 admins is needed.

Evidently the Office 365 subscription at work was of another type than your private one.
You would need to upgrade your subscription to use Planner.
It's your decision if it's worth the expense.